# fetching logged in user associated record in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin, cancancan

I have installed `rails_admin` gem without any error its display models crud too,but i have requirement in which i need to show `current_user` logged in associated data

> e.g User has many Books so in rails admin i want only that user book but currently it's showing all users books which is default behaviour of rails_admin

i have also try to use `cancancan` gem for achieve same thing but its not working my `rails_admin` initializers config as below

```
rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  ### Popular gems integration
  ## == Devise ==
   config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
   end
   config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
   config.parent_controller = 'ApplicationController'
  ## == Cancan ==
  config.authorize_with :cancan,UserAbility
  ## == Pundit ==
  # config.authorize_with :pundit
  config.included_models = ["Book","User"]
  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app
  end
end
```

UserAbility Class is implemented as below

```
  class UserAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
       if user.present?
         can :access, :dashboard
         can :manage, :Book,id:user.id
       end
  end
end
```

Comment: How is `Book` defined?  Do you have a foreign key to `User`?

Comment: yes i do have foreign key in book model

Comment: Mechanically speaking then, you'd want to get all books where the `user_id` is the same as the `current_user`.  Can you show where you're executing a query like that?

Comment: book contain attribute like `title`,`description` ,`user_id(foreign_key)`

Comment: i didn't execute any query `rails_admin` gem do for me,i can get all logged in user detail via `current_user.books` with rails way

Comment: Okay.  So maybe I misunderstood a bit.  Let's back up a bit; you say that a user has many books.  Is it the case then that a book can have many users?

Comment: no its not case ,i just need to fetch book based on the current logged user in `rails admin` gem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `can :manage, :Book,id:user.id`, try using:

```
can :read, Book, user_id: user.id
```

So the abilities together look like:

```
can :access, :rails_admin
can :dashboard
can :read, Book, user_id: user.id
```

Comment: yeah you are right ,but its still show me access denied page

Comment: @uzaif: what do you mean by "still show access denied"? This wasn't in the original description (unless I missed it). When is that happening? My guess would be that some part of the ability is misconfigured... see my edit above on how the abilities should be set up. I have a very similar setup in an old project, so I'd be surprised if this don't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding the scope of Rails Admin.  In essence, it's a snapshot of your database, and is meant for more administrative operations like querying your database for something specific.

The only thing you'd reasonably be able to do is to look up all `Book`s for a *given* user, with the default falling to *all* books for *all* users.  Filters exist within the display to be able to narrow down based on a user's specific credentials, such as user name, email, or ID.

For a conceptual check, a user in Rails Admin isn't treated or regarded the same as a user in your application.  Instead, think of using Rails Admin as a way to check the data in your database as opposed to showing data for a specific, authenticated person.

As you describe, the more appropriate Rails way to do this would be to create a controller and route for this data, and to simply use `current_user.books` to get all of the books for the current user.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation , i need to give privilege to normal user for accessing rails admin for manage only his/her books